# A be the occasion of B used in sentence, order of A and B?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, phrases, sentence

Is the sentence

> A battle over the production of bread in Paris was the occasion of Marie Antoinette's unfortunate remark about eating cake.

written in the right order? Is it grammatically correct? If so, why?

To me, I feel like it should go like this:

> Marie Antoinette's unfortunate remark about eating cake was the occasion of a battle over the production of bread in Paris.

Does the meaning of the sentence differ if it is to be written in my way?

Comment: With 'On the occasion of A, B happened' A is usually though not always the more salient event, and always earlier at least in principle ('On the occasion of his 75th birthday, WWII broke out'). With this in mind, I'd prefer the original here, though I'd not worry too much about your re-ordering.

Comment: Do you want to imply that Marie-Antoinette was prompted by the battle to make the remark, or that Marie-Antoinette's remark prompted the battle?

Comment: A remark, by the way, which she almost certainly never made.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inverse word order](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28067/inverse-word-order)

Comment: I think in the original sentence, "the occasion" goes together with "Marie Antoinette's unfortunate remark about eating cake." So, to invert it and keep the same meaning, you'd say "The occasion of Marie Antoinette's unfortunate remark about eating cake was a battle over the production of bread in Paris."

Comment: In that case, I'd prefer the original order, as the punchline comes at the end, so is more impactful that way. The inverted order, maybe may work better for certain audiences like young children whose attention spans may be shorter, so you may try to get their attention first by talking about Marie Antoinette's remark first.